# Javascript doesn't work after ajax gridview filter reload yii2

Tags: javascript, gridview, yii2, pjax

I did a simple gridview table with filters on yii2, seems to be working great, but I noticed the javascript functions doesn't work after I apply any filter on the gridview table, i think its refreshing the whole page instead only refresh the table.

I did the $.pjax.reload method but it didn't work, this is how i applied the pjax reload method:

```
//inventariosearch-amb_id is the ID of one of my filterselects on the gridview

$("#inventariosearch-amb_id").on("pjax:end", function() {
                $.pjax.reload({container:"#inventario_lista"});  //Reload GridView
            });
```

Let me know if i applied wrong the method.

well, as I said I think the pjax is refreshing the whole page cause it changes my page title from this:

[image: before_filter]

To this:

[image: after_filter]

That's how I notice the changes and the javascript doesn't work properly anymore.

What can I do?.

My view index.php:

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
use yii\helpers\Url;
use yii\grid\GridView;
use yii\grid\ActionColumn;
use yii\widgets\Pjax;
use yii\bootstrap4\Modal;
use app\models\Ambiente;
use app\models\TipoServicio;
use app\models\Empresa;
/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $dataProvider yii\data\ActiveDataProvider */

$this->registerJsFile("@web/js/inventario.js",[
    'depends' => [
        \yii\web\JqueryAsset::className()
    ]
]);

$this->title = 'Servidores';
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
?>
<div class="inventario-index">

    <?php $this->beginBlock('bloque_titulo'); ?>

        <div class="page-title-icon">
            <i class="fa fa-archive icon-gradient bg-arielle-smile">
            </i>
        </div>
        <div>
            <?= Html::encode($this->title) ?>
            <div class="page-title-subheading">
                Lista de servidores
            </div>
        </div>

    <?php $this->endBlock(); ?>

    <p>
        <?= Html::a('<i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Añadir nuevo', ['create'], ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
    </p>

    <?php Pjax::begin(['id'=>'inventario_lista','timeout'=> false,'clientOptions' => ['method' => 'POST','registerClientScript' => 'alert("lol")']]); ?>

    <?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $model,
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

            [
                'attribute' => 'amb_id',
                'value' => 'amb.amb_desc',
                'filter' => Html::activeDropDownList($model, 'amb_id', ArrayHelper::map(Ambiente::find()->asArray()->all(), 'amb_id', 'amb_desc'), [
                              'class' => 'form-control',
                              'prompt' => '--- Seleccione ---'
                        ]) 
            ],
            'inv_plataforma',
            'inv_host_computername',
            [
                'attribute' => 'tise_id',
                'value' => 'tise.tise_desc',
                'filter' => Html::activeDropDownList($model, 'tise_id',ArrayHelper::map(TipoServicio::find()->orderby(['tise_desc'=>SORT_ASC])->asArray()->all(), 'tise_id', 'tise_desc'), [
                              'class' => 'form-control',
                              'prompt' => '--- Seleccione ---'
                        ]) 
            ],
            [
                'attribute' => 'emp_id',
                'value' => 'emp.emp_desc',
                'filter' => Html::activeDropDownList($model, 'emp_id',ArrayHelper::map(Empresa::find()->orderby(['emp_desc'=>SORT_ASC])->asArray()->all(), 'emp_id', 'emp_desc'), [
                              'class' => 'form-control',
                              'prompt' => '--- Seleccione ---'
                        ]) 
            ],
            //'inv_servicio',
            //'inv_ip_admin',
            //'inv_ip_servicio',
            //'inv_ip_nfs',
            //'sad_id',
            //'usu_id_responsable_sistema',
            //'usu_id_2doresponsable_sistema',
            //'inv_modelo_servidor',
            //'prov_id',
            //'inv_serial_equipo',
            //'inv_codigo_remedy',
            //'inv_serial_dispositivo',
            //'sop_id',
            //'inv_version_so',
            //'inv_alta_disponibilidad',
            //'inv_ubicacion',
            //'inv_ala',
            //'inv_fila',
            //'inv_rack',
            //'inv_cpu_core',
            //'inv_cpu_modelo',
            //'inv_cpu_velocidad',
            //'inv_gb_memoria',
            //'hat_id',
            //'inv_tipo_contrato_proveedor',
            //'inv_responsable_funcional',
            //'spa_id',
            //'fv_id',
            //'pr_id',
            //'inv_observaciones',
            //'inv_performance_review',
            //'inv_performance_management',
            //'inv_obsoleto',
            //'inv_motivo_obsoleto',
            //'inv_arbol',
            //'inv_arbol_1er_nivel',
            //'inv_fin_venta',
            //'inv_fin_partes',
            //'inv_fin_soporte',
            //'inv_fecha_cons_obsoleto',

            ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
                'buttons'=>[
                    'view'=>
                        function($url,$model,$key){
                        $btn = Html::button("<i class='fa fa-eye'></i>",[
                            'value'=>Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl('inventario/view/'.$key),
                            'class'=>'serverview grid-action btn btn-info',
                            'title'=>'Ver datos del servidor',
                             'data-toggle'=> 'modal',
                             'data-target'=> '#modalviewserver',
                        ]);
                        return $btn;

                        },
                    'update'=>function ($url,$model,$key) {
                        return Html::a('<i class="fa fa-edit"></i>', ['/inventario/update/'.$key], ['class'=>'btn btn-success grid-button']);
                    },
                ],
            ],

        ],
    ]); ?>

    <?php Pjax::end(); ?>
</div>

    <?php

        Modal::begin([
                'title' => '<h4>Ver servidor</h4>',
                'id'     => 'modalviewserver',
                'size'   => 'modal-lg',

        ]);

        echo "<div id='viewservercontent'></div>";

        Modal::end();

    ?>
```

My action controller:

```
public function actionIndex()
    {
        $model = new InventarioSearch();
        $dataProvider = $model->search(Yii::$app->request->post());
        
        return $this->render('index', [
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'model' => $model
        ]);
    }
```

And my JS (just in case):

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    // $("#inventariosearch-amb_id").on("pjax:end", function() {
    //      $.pjax.reload({container:"#inventario_lista"});  //Reload GridView
    //  });
    
    $('.serverview').click(function()
    {
         $('#modalviewserver').appendTo("body").modal('show')
            .find('#viewservercontent')
             .load($(this).attr('value'));
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want your link to refresh whole page you have to remove your pjax.

Other way, try to set your javascript in `pjax:success` like this:

```
$(document).on('ready pjax:success', function(){
    //your javascript here    
    $('.serverview').click(function()
    {
        $('#modalviewserver').appendTo("body").modal('show')
        .find('#viewservercontent')
        .load($(this).attr('value'));
    });  
})
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for answer, but i think the pjax is refreshing the wholepage I just need only refresh the table, without reload the javascript files, because otherwise i have to add that sentence on each javascript file and each modification have to do the same

Comment: Pjax reload the whole page when timeout is not enough or your action return some error. Your timeout is false, so check if your action return 200 after pjax call or some error :)

Comment: yeah i did and it returns always 200, even i call the pjax error event and nothing appear :(

Comment: nope, just starts to fail after i use the first filter on the gridview

Comment: Try to use `GET` instead of `POST`

Comment: same result :(. I read that it is probably a yii2 bug with php7 but idk

Comment: if i use your suggestion it fails at first time and when i apply the filter it starts to work

Comment: what exactly fails first time? onclick function? Do you set it in `document:ready` and in `pjax:success`?

Comment: yes, i used the same code what you gave me

Comment: It doesn't sense.. Try to set only `document:ready` and say if it works.

Comment: if i let only the ready statement it works but after the filter, the onclick event doesnt work properly it turns my page black and doesnt show the modal. do you have skype or something to talk better?